# R raster: masking a raster by polygon also remove cells partially covered?

Tags: raster, r, masking

I want to mask out a raster based on the values of a polygon: i.e., set to NA all values of the raster that are not covered by the polygons. However, it seems that `raster::mask()` masks out cells (i.e. set them to NA) even if they are partially covered?

This is similar to the question: [Cropping a raster by a polygon - cells missing that are partially outside the polygon](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/230820/cropping-a-raster-by-a-polygon-cells-missing-that-are-partially-outside-the-po), but unlike `crop()`, `mask()` does not have the `snap="out"` option.

Check: here the right point of the triangle touches a cell, yet that cells is masked out.

```
library(raster)
library(sp)

r <- raster(xmn=1, xmx=5, ymn=1, ymx=5, nrows=4, ncols=4)
r[] <- 1:length(r)

Sr1 = Polygon(cbind(c(2,4,4,1,2),c(2,3,5,4,2)))
Sr2 = Polygon(cbind(c(4.1,4,2),c(2,3,2)))

SpP = SpatialPolygons(list(Polygons(list(Sr1), "s1"), Polygons(list(Sr2), "s2")), 1:2)

plot(mask(r, SpP))
plot(SpP,  add=TRUE)
```

[image]

Answer (score 20):

The documentation is indeed a little confusing. It states that:

> [...] all cells that are not covered by the Spatial object are
>   set to updatevalue

But actually, here *covered* means only if the cell's **centroid** is in the polygon. Indeed, `mask()` calls `rasterize()`, which states:

> For polygons, values are transferred if the polygon covers the center
>   of a raster cell.

The solution I found was to use `rasterize()` directly, with the `getCover=TRUE` option, which returns the coverage of each cell. Then set to NA values that have zero, and use that as the new mask:

```
SpP_ras <- rasterize(SpP, r, getCover=TRUE)
SpP_ras[SpP_ras==0] <- NA

plot(mask(r, SpP_ras))
plot(SpP,  add=TRUE)
```

[image]